# How to update query in Django using AJAX? or is it possible?

Tags: python, ajax, django

For example I have this in my template:

```
{% for pins in data %}
    <option type="text" value="{{pins.clandpin}}">{{pins.clandpin}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

And in my view.py:

```
def section_landpins(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
         section_id = request.GET['sectionid']
         m = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(ssectionid=section_id)
         data = serializers.serialize("json", m)
         return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

How do I use the response from my view.py in my template using AJAX?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formsection").change(function() {
        $('#forminput').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url : "/sectionpins",
            type : "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                'sectionid' : $(this).val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success : function(data){
               ......
            },
            error: function (){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
 });
```

Comment: In your success/error function you have data/xhr object that you can use, please clarify the question

Comment: I want to get the `data` from my `view.py`, don't mind the error. I want to update my query in my template.

Comment: With query do you mean the HTML-form (options)?

Comment: Yes, the user will select the section and the output in option will be base on the selected option value.

Answer (score 0):

If you render the from to a string like this, you can than put the HTML directly into the form,

```
def section_landpins(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        section_id = request.GET['sectionid']
        pins = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(ssectionid=section_id)
        html = render_to_string('pathToTemplate', {'pins ': pins })
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

Take the rendered HTML and put it into whereever you see fit using selectors.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formsection").change(function() {
        $('#forminput').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url : "/sectionpins",
            type : "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                'sectionid' : $(this).val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success : function(data){
                $('form').html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
                alert("xhr status: " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The `$('form').html(data);`, should be `$('#forminput').html(data);`? And in my template, what will be the structure?

Comment: I assume that you have a form around your option-values this form should have a class/ID as an example #myForm, this value should then be used in the jquery function like this: $('#myForm').html(data);
So if your form already have an ID (#forminput) it will work fine to use that like you suggested.

Comment: OK...BTW, here's my url.py, `url(r'^sectionpins$','tbl.views.section_landpins')` and the section select option is rendered in `index`, which is in separate function.

Answer (score 0):

you can test if a request use ajax

```
def section_landpins(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
         section_id = request.GET['sectionid']
         m = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(ssectionid=section_id)
         data = serializers.serialize("json", m)
         if request.is_ajax():
               return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
         else:
               rendre_to_response(........)
```